# iphone make personal delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, delegates

I have this problem....
in my viewcontroller.h I defined my class like this:

```
myClass* iR;
```

and after:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet myClass* iR;
```

into myClass.h I added this:

```
@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) didLogon:(bool)isLogged;
@end
```

and after:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<myClassDelegate> delegate;
```

now, into my class, in the connectionDidFinishLoading method ( I used a nsurlconnection to retrieve the login data I added this:

```
[self.delegate didLogon:true];
```

into myviewcontroller.h:

```
<myClassDelegate>
```

and into myviewcontroller.m:

```
-(void)didLogon:(bool)isLogged{
...
}
```

but the program go inside the self.delegate didLogon but into myviewcontroller.m didn't go... did you understand why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you assigning the delegate? You need something like this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
self.delegate = viewController;
```

Just to be safe, when you call delegate methods, call them like this:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didLogon:)]) {
    [self.delegate didLogon:YES];
}
```

That way, if the delegate doesn't support that method, your program won't crash when it doesn't recognize that selector.